# ENVIO DE FORMULARIO EN LA MISMA PAGINA

Tags: php, mysqli

Saludos estoy trabajando en un formulario php donde el mensaje de enviado se muestre en la misma pagina, mi inconveniente es el siguiente que a la hora de refrescar o actulizar la pagina (f5) se sigue mostrando el mensaje de (REGISTRO ENVIADO A NUESTRA BD EXITOSAMENTE ) y se inserta como un registro nuevo a la base de datos cuantas veces actualice la pagina.. como se podria hacer para q esto no sucediera?

```
require 'conexion.php';
    
$bandera = false;

if(!empty($_POST))

{

$cbx_activo = $_POST['cbx_activo'];

$cbx_marca = $_POST['cbx_marca'];

$cbx_modelo = $_POST['cbx_modelo'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla_registro (cbx_activo, cbx_marca, cbx_modelo ) VALUES ('$cbx_activo','$cbx_marca','$cbx_modelo')";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

if($resultado>0){

$bandera = true;
}
else
{
$error = "Ops! al parecer ocurrio un problema al enviar por favor intenta mas tarde.";}
}
```

---

### CODIGO HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="panel-body" >
                    
                <form  class="form-horizontal" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <h2>DATOS DE REGISTRO</h2>
                        </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cbx_activo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">DESCRIPCION</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select class="form-control" id="cbx_activo" name="cbx_activo">
                            <option value="">SELECCIONA</option>
                            <option value="VEHICULO">VEHICULO</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cbx_marca" class="col-sm-2 control-label">MARCA</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select class="form-control" id="cbx_marca" name="cbx_marca">
                            <option value="">SELECCIONA</option>
                            <option value="FORD">FORD</option>
                            <option value="TOYOTA">TOYOTA</option>
                            <option value="CHEVROLET">CHEVROLET</option>
                            <option value="FIAT">FIAT</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cbx_modelo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ESTADO</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select class="form-control" id="cbx_modelo" name="cbx_modelo">
                            <option value="">SELECCIONA</option>
                            <option value="AGENCIA">AGENCIA</option>
                            <option value="CHOCADO">CHOCADO</option>
                            <option value="USADO">USADO</option>
                            <option value="REPARACION">REPARACION</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Limpiar Campos</button>
                    </div>
               </div>

              
                    </form>
                    <style>
                        div._lFe{border-top:1px solid #bbb;border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;background:#f2f2f2;margin-top:1em;width:100%}
                        div._kFe{padding:0.5em 0;margin-left:10px}
                        div._jFe{margin-left:35px;margin-top:35px}
                    </style>
                    <?php if($bandera) { ?>
                    <div class="_lFe"><div class="_kFe"><font style="font-size:larger; color: green;"><b>REGISTRO ENVIADO A NUESTRA BD EXITOSAMENTE </b></font></div></div>
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="_lFe"><div class="_kFe"><font style="font-size:larger; color: red;"><?php echo isset($error) ? utf8_decode($error) : '' ; ?></b></font></div></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encuentro muchas formas de mejorar tu codigo. Ya que es muy inseguro lo que estas haciendo porque permitís que los atacantes ingresen a tu BD.

Yo te recomiendo realizar lo siguiente:

```
conexion.php
<?php
//Primero y antes que nada, no se como es tu conexion.php. Pero te recomiendo lo siguiente:
function OpenCon(){
     $dbhost = "localhost";
     $dbuser = "user";
     $dbpass = "password";
     $db = "database";
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);

     if($conn === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

     return $conn;
}

function CloseCon($conn){
     mysqli_close($conn);
}

?>
```

Una vez tenes eso en un archivo PHP aparte (lo cual te permitira realizar una conexion mas segura). Es hora de realizar la conexion.

```
<?php
require("conexion.php");

$bandera = false;

if(!empty($_POST))

{

$cbx_activo = $_POST['cbx_activo'];

$cbx_marca = $_POST['cbx_marca'];

$cbx_modelo = $_POST['cbx_modelo'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla_registro (cbx_activo, cbx_marca, cbx_modelo ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; //Aca está tu query, pero preparada para ser usada con statements preparados

$conn = OpenCon(); //invocamos a la funcion que abre la conexion.

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);// Le decimos a la conexion que se prepare con tu instruccion
$stmt->bind_params("sss", $cbx_activo, $cbx_marca, $cbx_modelo);//aca le damos los parametros para que los "cargue" en la base de datos. Los "sss" indican que lo que se presenta en el parentesis son tres strings. Si alguno de ellos es otro tipo de dato, cambiaselo.
/*
"s" = String
"i" = integer
"d" = double
"b" = boolean (si mal no me equivoco)
*/
$stmt->execute(); //ejecutamos

$resultado = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc(); //guardamos los resultados dentro de $resultado



if($resultado){ // si el resultado es verdadero..
#continua
$bandera = true;
// Te recomiendo hacer una pagina especial para el aviso de exito. 
header("exito.php");
exit; //SIEMPRE despues de usar header() utiliza exit; ya que previene errores.
}else{ 
 printf("Ops! al parecer ocurrio un problema al enviar por favor intenta mas tarde.");
} 


?>
```

Comment: Me funciono esta opcion como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer un redirect en tu archivo php, cuando se envia el mensaje...

hay varias formas, te paso dos ideas que se me ocurren ahora
1)

```
echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('REGISTRO ENVIADO A NUESTRA BD EXITOSAMENTE');
    window.location.href='dirección del formulario o index.php o a donde lo quiereas enviar';
    </script>");
```

2. 

```
header('Location:dirección del formulario o index.php o a donde lo quiereas enviar?message=exito');
```

con ese pedazo de código re direccianas al usuario a la pag que le indiques sin mensaje de exito... Peroooo estas enviando a la pantalla que redireccionaste via URL una variable que te puede servir para mostrar un mensaje... osea:

Si direccianas a index.php
haces esto

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['message']) && $_GET['message']=='exito'){
echo "REGISTRO ENVIADO A NUESTRA BD EXITOSAMENTE";
}
?>
```

Obviamente que despues le das los estilos al mensaje y lo acomodas a tus inquietudes!, espero que te haya servido!